# cordova - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

While Build the bundle using cordova command, i am getting following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project name'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\project_name\platforms\android\gradlew -b D:\project_name\platforms\android\build.gradle :app:bundleRelease
```

**Gradle version:**
Gradle 8.3
Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          1.8.0_301 (Oracle Corporation 25.301-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

**Java version:**
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cordova Android 12 supports AGP_VERSION 7.4.2. And they bumped the Java version. In your case, Gradle JDK version 1.8 => 11 or 17 should fix the issue

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/05/22/cordova-android-12.0.0.html

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1539